# Older Moen Bathroom Faucet -- How to remove?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I'm trying to release the sink faucet and handles. The lower part of each handle unscrews and gives me about 1/8" above the sink itself, but I don't see any hidden screws underneath. How do I remove these?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look underneath the sink where the supply hoses are. There should be a nut holding the faucet to the sink. Once removed the handle can be lifted from the surface.

Comment: That was it. I had to remove some of the concrete underlayment to access the nuts. Thank you.